# Importing my modules into Flask app error

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a Flask app and have already created a python script to work with the app. However I cannot get this script to import at all. When I start the Flask app I get the error:

> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'getmail'`.

getmail is imported as so:

```
import getmail
```

However I have tried to move getmail.py to a folder called getmail and added an empty __init__.py file. Then importing it like so (I have also tried using from getMail.getmail import getmail as there is a function named getmail in there too):

```
sys.path.append('C:\Users\Rob\Current Projects\Good-Mail\Good-Mail\Dev\Backend\flaskr\getMail')
import getMail.getmail
```

Here is my file structure without moving getmail.py into its own folder:

```
└───flaskr
    │   getmail.py
    │   receiveTest2.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───__pycache__
            getmail.cpython-39.pyc
            __init__.cpython-39.pyc
```

Here is my file structure after moving getmail.py into its own directory:

```
C:.
└───flaskr
    │   receiveTest2.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───getMail
    │       getmail.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    └───__pycache__
            getmail.cpython-39.pyc
            __init__.cpython-39.pyc
```

In case this is useful when __init__.py is executed on it's own (i.e. not with `flask --app flaskr run --debug`. It doesn't show any import errors.

Comment: My guess that you're following the Flask tutorial - you want `from flaskr.getMail import getmail` (or using your first attempt `from flaskr import getmail`.